# How to access EFS from kubernetes sa in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I deployed an EFS in AWS and a test pod on EKS from this document: [Amazon EFS CSI driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html).

EFS CSI Controller pods in the `kube-system`:

```
kube-system    efs-csi-controller-5bb76d96d8-b7qhk        3/3     Running   0          26s
kube-system    efs-csi-controller-5bb76d96d8-hcgvc        3/3     Running   0          26s
```

After deployed a sample application from the doc, when confirm `efs-csi-controller` sa pod logs, it seems they didn't work well.

Pod 1:

```
$ kubectl logs efs-csi-controller-5bb76d96d8-b7qhk \
>     -n kube-system \
>     -c csi-provisioner \
>     --tail 10
W1030 08:15:59.073406       1 feature_gate.go:235] Setting GA feature gate Topology=true. It will be removed in a future release.
I1030 08:15:59.073485       1 feature_gate.go:243] feature gates: &{map[Topology:true]}
I1030 08:15:59.073500       1 csi-provisioner.go:132] Version: v2.1.1-0-g353098c90
I1030 08:15:59.073520       1 csi-provisioner.go:155] Building kube configs for running in cluster...
I1030 08:15:59.087072       1 connection.go:153] Connecting to unix:///var/lib/csi/sockets/pluginproxy/csi.sock
I1030 08:15:59.087512       1 common.go:111] Probing CSI driver for readiness
I1030 08:15:59.090672       1 csi-provisioner.go:202] Detected CSI driver efs.csi.aws.com
I1030 08:15:59.091694       1 csi-provisioner.go:244] CSI driver does not support PUBLISH_UNPUBLISH_VOLUME, not watching VolumeAttachments
I1030 08:15:59.091997       1 controller.go:756] Using saving PVs to API server in background
I1030 08:15:59.092834       1 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease kube-system/efs-csi-aws-com...
```

Pod 2:

```
$ kubectl logs efs-csi-controller-5bb76d96d8-hcgvc \
>     -n kube-system \
>     -c csi-provisioner \
>     --tail 10
I1030 08:16:32.628759       1 controller.go:1099] Final error received, removing PVC 111111a-d6fb-440a-9bb1-132901jfas from claims in progress
W1030 08:16:32.628783       1 controller.go:958] Retrying syncing claim "111111a-d6fb-440a-9bb1-132901jfas", failure 5
E1030 08:16:32.628798       1 controller.go:981] error syncing claim "111111a-d6fb-440a-9bb1-132901jfas": failed to provision volume with StorageClass "efs-sc": rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = Access Denied. Please ensure you have the right AWS permissions: Access denied
I1030 08:16:32.628845       1 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"default", Name:"efs-claim", UID:"111111a-d6fb-440a-9bb1-132901jfas", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1724705", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'ProvisioningFailed' failed to provision volume with StorageClass "efs-sc": rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = Access Denied. Please ensure you have the right AWS permissions: Access denied
I1030 08:17:04.628997       1 controller.go:1332] provision "default/efs-claim" class "efs-sc": started
I1030 08:17:04.629193       1 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"default", Name:"efs-claim", UID:"111111a-d6fb-440a-9bb1-132901jfas", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1724705", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Provisioning' External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/efs-claim"
I1030 08:17:04.687957       1 controller.go:1099] Final error received, removing PVC 111111a-d6fb-440a-9bb1-132901jfas from claims in progress
W1030 08:17:04.687977       1 controller.go:958] Retrying syncing claim "111111a-d6fb-440a-9bb1-132901jfas", failure 6
E1030 08:17:04.688001       1 controller.go:981] error syncing claim "111111a-d6fb-440a-9bb1-132901jfas": failed to provision volume with StorageClass "efs-sc": rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = Access Denied. Please ensure you have the right AWS permissions: Access denied
I1030 08:17:04.688044       1 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"default", Name:"efs-claim", UID:"111111a-d6fb-440a-9bb1-132901jfas", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"1724705", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'ProvisioningFailed' failed to provision volume with StorageClass "efs-sc": rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = Access Denied. Please ensure you have the right AWS permissions: Access denied
```

From the events, I can see:

```
$ kubectl get events
27m         Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/efs-app                                    skip schedule deleting pod: default/efs-app
7m38s       Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/efs-app                                    0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
7m24s       Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/efs-app                                    0/2 nodes are available: 2 persistentvolumeclaim "efs-claim" is being deleted.
7m24s       Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/efs-app                                    skip schedule deleting pod: default/efs-app
17s         Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/efs-app                                    0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
27m         Normal    ExternalProvisioning     persistentvolumeclaim/efs-claim                waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "efs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
10m         Normal    ExternalProvisioning     persistentvolumeclaim/efs-claim                waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "efs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
11m         Normal    Provisioning             persistentvolumeclaim/efs-claim                External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/efs-claim"
11m         Warning   ProvisioningFailed       persistentvolumeclaim/efs-claim                failed to provision volume with StorageClass "efs-sc": rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = Access Denied. Please ensure you have the right AWS permissions: Access denied
7m47s       Normal    Provisioning             persistentvolumeclaim/efs-claim                External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/efs-claim"
7m47s       Warning   ProvisioningFailed       persistentvolumeclaim/efs-claim                failed to provision volume with StorageClass "efs-sc": rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = Access Denied. Please ensure you have the right AWS permissions: Access denied
74s         Normal    ExternalProvisioning     persistentvolumeclaim/efs-claim                waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "efs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
2m56s       Normal    Provisioning             persistentvolumeclaim/efs-claim                External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/efs-claim"
2m56s       Warning   ProvisioningFailed       persistentvolumeclaim/efs-claim                failed to provision volume with StorageClass "efs-sc": rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = Access Denied. Please ensure you have the right AWS permissions: Access denied
```

`ServiceAccount` was created by:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: efs-csi-controller-sa
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-efs-csi-driver
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/AmazonEKS_EFS_CSI_Driver_Policy
```

The `AmazonEKS_EFS_CSI_Driver_Policy` is the json from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/v1.3.2/docs/iam-policy-example.json).

---

## Example code

storageclass.yaml

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  fileSystemId: fs-92107410
  directoryPerms: "700"
  gidRangeStart: "1000" # optional
  gidRangeEnd: "2000" # optional
  basePath: "/dynamic_provisioning" # optional
```

pod.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: efs-app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: centos
      command: ["/bin/sh"]
      args: ["-c", "while true; do echo $(date -u) >> /data/out; sleep 5; done"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data
  volumes:
    - name: persistent-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: efs-claim
```

Comment: Your EFS CSI seems OK, can you post the complete StorageClass, PersistentVolumeClaim, PersistentVolume and the consuming resource (eg. pod? deployment?) spec.

Comment: @gohm'c I just used the example source. I added them to the end of the question.

Comment: do you have an OIDC provider for your cluster?

Comment: Can you post logs from **efs-csi-controller** pod ?

Comment: @RezaNasiri Yes, I created it by [Terraform](https://echo.notable.app/131bca104af406209f7a023b080f8f2aa9ab07ae139e9eed69e17f8f156f9d1d).

Comment: @Cloudziu I posted them `Pod1`, `Pod2`.

Comment: the ones you posted here are IAM role and policy but in addition to that you need to have a OIDC provider enabled for your cluster. If you are using terraform eks module, there is a "enable_irsa" input you can use to create the provider or use this link to do it yourself https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/enable-iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

Comment: @RezaNasiri Thank you very much. I didn't use eks module in Terraform but by pure resources. I created aws_iam_openid_connect_provider for the cluster. Maybe the eks_oidc_assume_role_for_efs role policy document is using the different data. I added a new one at the bottom [here](https://echo.notable.app/546f9805630124d7683648a4d7d4242b3a42e8f2eff3c10bebb782f0dbdfdbaa).

Comment: check the controller pods to make sure AWS_ROLE_ARN and AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE environment variables exist. then check the CloudTrail to see why AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity is failing. there might be a typo somewhere that is causing this but basically the controller pods cannot use the IAM policy you have created

Comment: @RezaNasiri I checked the controller pod's description `kubectl describe po efs-csi-controller-5bb76d96d8-b7qhk -n kube-system`. I didn't find the two environment variables you mentioned. Where to set them? I also checked the CloudTrail, but didn't find `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` in the json file.

Comment: you don't need to set them, they will be injected into the pod if it is setup to use the service account you created and the service account is annotated to use the IAM role

Comment: @RezaNasiri Thank you very much. It seems the sa and the annotation didn't work well. I will check it.

Comment: Hi @Miantian, did you check it? Is it working?

Comment: @MikolajS. Yeah, the reason was the efs driver image is using the different region from mine. I changed to the right one and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted community wiki answer for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

Based on @Miantian comment:

> The reason was the efs driver image is using the different region from mine. I changed to the right one and it works.

You can find steps to setup the Amazon EFS CSI driver in the proper region in [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html).